# Alexa Skills Kit "Skill execution returned an exception for requestId" error

Tags: python, json, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

I'm very new to the Alexa Skills Kit. And I`ve been trying to make a simple music player skill on a web hosted server in [https://www.pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/). When I try to make a request a

> "SKILL_ENDPOINT_ERROR"

is captured in the device log with the following description:

> "Skill execution returned an exception for requestId
> amzn1.echo-api.request.e08ec414-0a30-4e95-87bb-28f315c8d4eb".

This is my skill request handler code:

```
from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder
from ask_sdk_core.utils import is_intent_name, is_request_type
from flask import Flask
from flask_ask_sdk.skill_adapter import SkillAdapter
from ask_sdk_model.ui import SimpleCard

app = Flask(__name__)
sb = SkillBuilder()


#VARIABLES
Current_song = ""
silent_mode = False

"""/////////////////////////
//  Request Handlers  //
////////////////////////"""

#Launch request
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_request_type("LaunchRequest"))
def launch_request_handler(handler_input):

    speech_text = "What do you wish to play?"

    return handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech_text).set_card(
        SimpleCard("Hello World", speech_text)).set_should_end_session(
        False).response

#Session Ended Request
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_request_type("SessionEndedRequest"))
def session_ended_request_handler(handler_input):

    return handler_input.response_builder.response

"""/////////////////////////
//  ASK Intent Handlers  //
////////////////////////"""

#Help Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("AMAZON.HelpIntent"))
def help_intent_handler(handler_input):

    speech_text = "You can ask me to play something on your server!"

    return handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech_text).ask(
        speech_text).set_card(SimpleCard(
            "Wha can I do", speech_text)).response

#Stop Skill intent
@sb.request_handler(
    can_handle_func=lambda handler_input:
        is_intent_name("AMAZON.CancelIntent")(handler_input) or
        is_intent_name("AMAZON.StopIntent")(handler_input))
def cancel_and_stop_intent_handler(handler_input):

    speech_text = "Goodbye!"

    return handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech_text).set_card(
        SimpleCard("Hello World", speech_text)).response

#FallBack Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("AMAZON.FallbackIntent"))
def fallback_handler(handler_input):

    speech = (
        "I can't help you with that.  "
        "You can ask me to play music!")
    reprompt = "You can ask me to play music!"
    handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech).ask(reprompt)
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

"""/////////////////////////
//  Bot Intent Handlers  //
////////////////////////"""

#Play Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("PlayIntent"))
def Play_intent_handler(handler_input):
    song_value = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots["music"].value

    if song_value:
            speak_output = "Now playing {} on our server.".format(song_value)
            Current_song = song_value
    else:
            speak_output = "I dont know what you want to play."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).ask(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Playing {}...".format(song_value), speak_output))
    
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Pause Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("PauseIntent"))
def Pause_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Paused."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Pause", speak_output))
    
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Loop Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("LoopIntent"))
def Loop_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Song loop enabled."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Loop", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Restart Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("RestartIntent"))
def Restart_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Restarting current song"

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Restart", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Resume Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("ResumeIntent"))
def Resume_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Resumed."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Resume", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Now Playing Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("NowPlayingIntent"))
def Now_Playing_intent_handler(handler_input):
    
    if Current_song:
        speak_output = "Now playing {}.".format(Current_song)
    else:
        speak_output = "There is nothing playing at the moment"

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Now Playing", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Print Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("PrintIntent"))
def Print_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Printed."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Print", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Remove Number Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("RemoveNumIntent"))
def Remove_Num_intent_handler(handler_input):
    num_value = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots["MusicNum"].value
    
    if num_value:
        speak_output = "Removed song number {} from queue".format(num_value)
    else:
        speak_output = "There is no song in number {}".format(num_value)

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).ask(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Remove", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Remove Position Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("RemovePosIntent"))
def Remove_Pos_intent_handler(handler_input):
    pos_value = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots["MusicPos"].value
    
    if pos_value:
        speak_output = "Removed {} song from queue.".format(pos_value)
    else:
        speak_output = "There is no {} song in queue.".format(pos_value)

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).ask(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Remove", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Remove All Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("RemoveALLIntent"))
def Remove_All_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "All songs removed from queue"

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Remove", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Back Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("BackIntent"))
def Back_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Went back a song in queue."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Back", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Skip Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("SkiptIntent"))
def Skip_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Skipped."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Skip", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Shuffle Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("ShuffleIntent"))
def Shuffle_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Shuffled queue."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Shuffle", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Skip to number Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("SkipToNumIntent"))
def Skip_To_Num_intent_handler(handler_input):
    num_value = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots["MusicNum"].value
    
    if num_value:
        speak_output = "Skiped to song number {}.".format(num_value)
    else:
        speak_output = "There is no {} song in queue.".format(num_value)

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).ask(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Skip To", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Skip to position Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("SkipToPosIntent"))
def Skip_To_Pos_intent_handler(handler_input):
    pos_value = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots["MusicPos"].value
    
    if pos_value:
        speak_output = "Skiped to {} song in queue.".format(pos_value)
    else:
        speak_output = "There is no {} song in queue.".format(pos_value)

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).ask(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Skip To", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Loop queue Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("LoopQueueIntent"))
def Loop_Queue_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Looped queue."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Loop Queue", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Silent Mode Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("SilentModeIntent"))
def Silent_Mode_intent_handler(handler_input):

    silent_mode = True

    return handler_input.response_builder.response

#Disconnect Intent
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("DisconnectIntent"))
def Disconnect_intent_handler(handler_input):
    speak_output = "Disconnected."

    if silent_mode == False:
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).set_card(SimpleCard("Disconnect", speak_output))
    return handler_input.response_builder.response

sa = SkillAdapter(skill=sb.create(), skill_id="amzn1.ask.skill.e5e95d9a-6047-41aa-96f1-879b88421432", app=app)

"""/////////////////////////
//  Exception Handlers  //
////////////////////////"""

#Exception Handler
@sb.exception_handler(can_handle_func=lambda i, e: True)
def all_exception_handler(handler_input, exception):

    speech = "Sorry, there was some problem. Please try again!!"
    handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech).ask(speech)

    return handler_input.response_builder.response


@app.route("/")
def invoke_skill():
    return sa.dispatch_request()
```

I first assumed the problem was that I didn't have an Exeption Handler, but there was no change in the result since I implemented one.

Has anyone solved this issue or has any idea what my code is missing?